# Gronwall-like inequality

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f$ be a smooth non-negative function on $[0,\infty)$. For all $t_1\leq t_2$, consider the integral inequality
$$f(t_2)+C_1\int_{t_1}^{t_2}f(s)\,\mathrm{d}s\leq C_2K(t_2-t_1)+f(t_1),$$
where $K>0$ and $0<C_1<1<C_2$ are constants. I would like to show that
$$f(t)\leq C_2(K+f(0)),$$
but I am not sure how to prove it and if it is even true. A hint would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complete change. I did first not see that the second word is "smooth". Then the inequality can be transposed to
$$
\frac{f(t_2)-f(t_1)}{t_2-t_1}+\frac{C_1}{t_2-t_1}\int_{t_1}^{t_2}f(s)\,ds\le C_2K
$$
Because of the smoothness, this translates into the differential inequality
$$
f'(t)+C_1f(t)\le C_2K
$$
which has the solution 
$$
f(t_2)\le f(t_1)e^{-C_1(t_2-t_1)}+\tfrac{C_2K}{C_1}\bigl(1-e^{-C_1(t_2-t_1)}\bigr)\le \max\bigl(f(t_1),\tfrac{C_2K}{C_1}\bigr)
$$

Comment: How do you conclude that $F(t)\leq F(0)e^{-Ct}$? What is wrong with the following argument? $$F(t)=\exp(\ln F(t))=\exp(\ln F(0)+\int_0^t\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s}\ln F(s)\,\mathrm{d}s)\geq\exp(\ln F(0)-Ct)= e^{-Ct}F(0)$$

Comment: Yes, there was a wrong conclusion. But since $f$ is assumed to be smooth, a radically simplified approach is possible.